# Do we want to allow question about specific open source products?

Tags: discussion, scope

[Differences between Firefox and Iceweasel](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/541/168) is a question that isn't directly about open source, but rather about an open source product. This is not exactly included in our scope as it is, but could possibly be a good addition?

It should be noted that this question is entirely different from a hypothetical question like "How do I open an incognito tab in Iceweasel?", which is still a question about an open source product, but has nothing at all to do with it being open source.

**Do we want to allow questions about open source products?**
And if so:
**Under what conditions?**

Comment: Note that I'm not asking about this question specifically and rather about this class of questions. If your opinions of this class of questions differs from your opinion of the question itself for whatever reason, you can mention it but don't make it the meat of your answer, that discussion can go elsewhere.

Comment: I think this is very related: http://meta.opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/154/should-we-allow-case-studies

Comment: @Zizouz212 was the linked question deleted? I think it's useful to have a history of discussions that occurred, whatever the outcome, so I'm just wondering...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are technical questions about specific software that happens to be open source on-topic?](http://meta.opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/150/are-technical-questions-about-specific-software-that-happens-to-be-open-source-o)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, a question about how Debian chooses to maintain their own fork of Firefox is off-topic. If Debian chose to link with different libraries, or add built-in support for ASCII art rendering or other technical differences, that's not relevant here.

However, it is on-topic to ask what led Debian to make a fork even though they didn't mean to introduce technical differences, and what Debian changes from Firefox in order to meet these objectives. It's not a great question, because [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Corporation_software_rebranded_by_the_Debian_project) covers it, but it's on-topic.

I've [suggested an edit to this effect](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/148).

Comment: This seems fair, questions about why specific open source projects fork or license a certain way can still provide a steady stream of questions in the long term but are sure to be on-topic. I suppose the reason I was inclined to allow the question was because the question you edited it into was already implicitly present.